# log4net is logging to two files simultaneously

Tags: asp.net-mvc, log4net

I have two loggers, one called NotificationLogger and one called VMPLogger. For some reason, no matter which logger I call, it writes to both logs!

**My web.config**

```
  <log4net>
    <appender name="VMPLogger" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="logs\vmp_" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <staticLogFileName value="false" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <datePattern value="yyyyMM'.log'" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="NotificationLogger" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="logs\notifications_" />
      <staticLogFileName value="false" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <datePattern value="yyyyMM'.log'" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="VMPLogger" />
      <appender-ref ref="NotificationLogger" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

**My public loggers (in global.asax)**

```
    public static readonly ILog VmpLogger = LogManager.GetLogger("VMPLogger");
    public static readonly ILog NotificationLogger = LogManager.GetLogger("NotificationLogger");

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    }
```

**My test controller action**

```
    public void LogSomethingNotification()
    {
        MvcApplication.NotificationLogger.Info("Something");
    }
```

Can anyone see why from this code/config? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It because GetLogger does not get an appender, but a specific logger. You need to filter in the appender which logger you want to see. Add filters in your appenders to log only one of your loggers:

```
<log4net>
<appender name="VMPLogger" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="logs\vmp_" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <datePattern value="yyyyMM'.log'" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">
    <loggerToMatch value="VMPLogger" />
  </filter>     
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
</appender>
<appender name="NotificationLogger" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="logs\notifications_" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <datePattern value="yyyyMM'.log'" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">
    <loggerToMatch value="NotificationLogger" />
  </filter>     
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
</appender>
<root>
  <level value="ALL" />
  <appender-ref ref="VMPLogger" />
  <appender-ref ref="NotificationLogger" />
</root>
```

Comment: You can have a look at something like:
`log4net.LogManager.GetAllRepositories()[0].GetAppenders()[0].DoAppend(....);`